# How to enable concurrent outgoing RDP sessions?

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop

On Windows 7 and below, I can easily fire up multiple RDP sessions to remote servers. Under Windows 8, when I run RDP a second time, it just brings the first instance to the foreground. How can I launch multiple RDP sessions? I wish to do this with the traditional desktop RDP app, not the new Remote Desktop App from the App store.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can click on the taskbar icon with the middle mouse button to open another instance of the Remote Desktop client. Or, right-click the icon and start another instance from the jumplist.

[image]

Alternatively, you may want to have a look at [mRemoteNG](http://www.mremoteng.org/), which can open multiple RDP connections in a tabbed interface.

[image]

Please note that it requires the .NET framework v2 which is not installed in Windows by default (but can be installed through the "Turn Windows features on or off" interface).

[image]

Comment: Searching for remote from the modern UI, right clicking on the search result, and then selecting "Open New Window" from the bottom menu works as well.

Comment: I think Shift+Click still behaves like middle click as well in Win 8, if you prefer.

Comment: You could run mstsc.exe /v <computer name> from the console instead - that opens a new instance up each time you run it.

Answer (score 4):

This "issue" does not affect only RDP, but other applications as well - it's just the way Windows 8 start menu works.

If you're primarily a keyboard user and prefer to start apps the "old way" by opening the start menu, typing in the first few letters, and then hitting enter, there's a way to launch new instances in Windows 8 too:

- Pressing "**Enter**" will start the application, or will focus the window if it's already running
- Pressing "**Shift+Enter**" will start a *new instance* even if the application is already running

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is Microsoft's own Remote Desktop Connection Manager http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21101

Answer (score 0):

Some other options ...
In Windows 8, right click the RPD the icon and select "open in new window"
Or select "Open file locaton" and pull out a copy of the shortcut "Remote Desktop Connection" to the desktop.